# Set double spacing between the list figure captions

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, captions

I am using a PhD thesis template define list of figures as following:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLASS OPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\ifbool{parskip}{\RequirePackage{parskip}} % If the parskip option is passed to the class, require the parskip package 


\ifbool{listtoc}{% If the liststotoc option has been passed to the class, add the lists to the table of contents
    \patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@starttoc{lot}}{%
        \addchaptertocentry{\listtablename}\@starttoc{lot}%
    }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@starttoc{lof}}{%
        \addchaptertocentry{\listfigurename}\@starttoc{lof}%
    }{}{}%
}

\ifbool{toctoc}{% If the toctotoc options has been passed to the class, add the table of contents to the table of contents
    \patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}%
}{%
    \addchaptertocentry{\contentsname}\@starttoc{toc}}{}{}%
}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\MakeUppercase}{\MakeMarkcase}{}{}

% If the option `nolistspacing' is given, the spacing in the different lists is reduced to single spacing. This option is only useful, if the spacing of the document has been changed to onehalfspacing or doublespacing.
\ifbool{nolistspace}{
    \patchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
        \@starttoc{lof}
    }{%
        \begingroup%
        \singlespace\@starttoc{lof}\endgroup%
    }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\listoftables}{%
        \@starttoc{lot}
    }{%
        \begingroup%
        \singlespace\@starttoc{lot}\endgroup%
    }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{%
        \@starttoc{toc}
    }{%
        \begingroup%
        \singlespace\@starttoc{toc}\endgroup%
    }{}{}%
}{}
```

I need to change the spacing between each figure caption to `\doublespacing`, but preserve a `\singlespacing` within the figure caption itself. Or can I achieve this elsewhere in the main file.

Answer (score 0):

To me it is unclear what code you are using in your document. What is the general spacing? Are you using the `nolistspacing` class option? See the class code below for what that does.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CLASS OPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


% If the option `nolistspacing' is given, the spacing in the different lists is reduced to single spacing. This option is only useful, if the spacing of the document has been changed to onehalfspacing or doublespacing.
\ifbool{nolistspace}{
    \patchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
        \@starttoc{lof}
    }{%
        \begingroup%
        \singlespace\@starttoc{lof}\endgroup%
    }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\listoftables}{%
        \@starttoc{lot}
    }{%
        \begingroup%
        \singlespace\@starttoc{lot}\endgroup%
    }{}{}%
    \patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{%
        \@starttoc{toc}
    }{%
        \begingroup%
        \singlespace\@starttoc{toc}\endgroup%
    }{}{}%
}{}
```

Note that it sets `singlespace` for the LoF, LoT, and ToC. If you don't want a `singlespace` LoF change the `singlespace` to `onehalfspace` or `doublespace`, whatever is your setting for the document as a whole.

Or, untested, in the main document try

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \@starttoc{lof}
}{%
   \begingroup%
   doublespace\@starttoc{lof}\endgroup%
}{}{}%
\makeatother

....
\listoffigures
....
```

Or, perhaps more simply (also untested)

```
\begin{doublespace}
  \listoffigures
\end{doublespace}
```

Comment: The general spacing is set to \singlespacing. Here, I want to keep the \singlespacing, but change the spacing between different captions in the list of figures to \doublespacing. I tried the solution, but non is working

Comment: The `\begin{doublespace} \listoffigures \end{doublespace}` works with the `article` and `book` classes. Perhaps you can ask the supplier of the class you are using for help.